# Issue with select box value not getting pre selected in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is my select box option not getting selected on load?

As you can see from the script below there is already a class_id there in the "ng-model" of the select box still it doesn't gets that value selected in the option with the class_id present in the option.

Upon select box change the "ng-model" gets updated and the model also gets updated with the class_id of the option.

Need to set select box option to the pre selected class_id of the option.

Fiddle for the same is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kushal812/kmkhvudu/)

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("test", function($scope) {
    $scope.cartData = {
      order: [{
        class_id: 1,
        price: 121
      }, {
        class_id: 2,
        price: 11
      }],
      selectedSection: {
        classes: [{
          class_id: 1,
          name: "adsad"
        }, {
          class_id: 2,
          name: "2222"
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <ul class="bxslider" ng-controller="test">{{test}}
    <li class="mbm" ng-repeat="seat in cartData.order">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="select-style">
          Selected id: {{seat.class_id}}
          <select ng-options="type.class_id as type.name for type in cartData.selectedSection.classes track by type.class_id" ng-model="seat.class_id">
            <!-- <option ng-repeat="type in cartData.selectedSection.classes" value="{{type.class_id}}">{{type.name}}</option> -->
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="price-sec">
          <span class="price">Price: {{seat.price}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `track by type.class_id` from `ng-options`.As the angular doc says

> Using select as will bind the result of the select expression to the
>   model, but the value of the  and  html elements will
>   be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for
>   object data sources) of the value within the collection. If a track by
>   expression is used, the result of that expression will be set as the
>   value of the option and select elements.

```
$scope.items = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];
```

This will work:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
$scope.selected = $scope.items[0];

but this will not work:

<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
$scope.selected = $scope.items[0].subItem;
```

> In both examples, the track by expression is applied successfully to
>   each item in the items array. Because the selected option has been set
>   programmatically in the controller, the track by expression is also
>   applied to the ngModel value. In the first example, the ngModel value
>   is items[0] and the track by expression evaluates to items[0].id with
>   no issue. In the second example, the ngModel value is items[0].subItem
>   and the track by expression evaluates to items[0].subItem.id (which is
>   undefined). As a result, the model value is not matched against any
>    and the  appears as having no selected value.

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("test", function($scope) {
    $scope.cartData = {
      order: [{
        class_id: 1,
        price: 121
      }, {
        class_id: 2,
        price: 11
      }],
      selectedSection: {
        classes: [{
          class_id: 1,
          name: "adsad"
        }, {
          class_id: 2,
          name: "2222"
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <ul class="bxslider" ng-controller="test">{{test}}
    <li class="mbm" ng-repeat="seat in cartData.order">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="select-style">
          Selected id: {{seat.class_id}}
          <select ng-options="type.class_id as type.name for type in cartData.selectedSection.classes " ng-model="seat.class_id">
            <!-- <option ng-repeat="type in cartData.selectedSection.classes" value="{{type.class_id}}">{{type.name}}</option> -->
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="price-sec">
          <span class="price">Price: {{seat.price}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```